# How to validate the presence of attributes when updating a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am new to rails and I try to find a validation method corresponding to validate the presence of an attribute when updating a record. If that attribute is not present, meaning the attribute does not exist from the request body, Rails should not update the record.

```
validates :description, presence: true
```

and

```
validates_presence_of :description
```

doesn't seem to do the job. Is there a method for this purpose? It seems quite common in every day scenarios.

Comment: This should work. Can you paste more of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say:

```
model.update(hash_that_has_no_description_key)
```

then you're not touching `:description`: sending a hash without a `:description` key to `update` is not the same as sending in a hash with `:description => nil`. If `model` is already valid (i.e. it has a description) then that `update` won't invalidate it because it won't touch `:description`.

You say this:

> If that attribute is not present, meaning the attribute does not exist from the request body, Rails should not update the record.

Since you're talking about the *request body* (which models really shouldn't know anything about) then you should be dealing with this logic in the controller as it prepares the incoming data for the `update` call.

You could check in the controller and complain:

```
data = whatever_params
if(!data.has_key?(:description))
  # Complain in an appropriate manner...
end
# Continue as now...
```

or you could include `:description => nil` if there is no `:description`:

```
def whatever_params
  data = params.require(...).permit(...)
  data[:description] = data[:description].presence # Or however you prefer to do this...
  data
end
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should use before_update..

see this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks

but use before_update instead before_save..